# How are the bitwise operators used to only clear a single condition state on a C++ stream?

Tags: c++, iostream

How does the following code works to clear **only** the failbit in the `cin` stream?

```
cin.clear(cin.rdstate() & ~cin.failbit);
```

I am highly confused, as I was under the impression that `cin.rdstate()` returns an object of type `iostate`. This is then somehow compared with a single bit (`cin.failbit`) to clear only said bit. How exactly do the `&` and `~` work to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit

Comment: `iostate` is a type for which bitwise operations are allowed (which means it is either an integral type, or a type with defined operators that have "like integer" semantics).   `cin.failbit` will have only the fail bit(s) set, `~cin.failbit` will have all bits EXCEPT the fail bit(s) set.   The `&` then gives the result of clearing only the fail-related bits of `rdstate()`.

Comment: Just a hint. 'Bit' is note a variable type in C/C++. The closest to it would be `bool`. What you see there is not 'a single bit', but a number. Bitwise operators (e.g. &, ~) work on numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit)